# Include graphics links in table of contents

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents

I've written a simple (automatized) report which includes many graphics by simple `\includegraphics`. Now I'd like to generate a table of contents link for each graphics which I can click due to package `hyperref`. So I wrote

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Start}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{mwe/example-image-a.pdf}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{A}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{mwe/example-image-a.pdf}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{A}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{mwe/example-image-a.pdf}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{A}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{mwe/example-image-b.pdf}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{B}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{mwe/example-image-a.pdf}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{A}
\end{document}
```

(not sure how MWE works :/). However, in the generated table of contents in the PDF, the links in the TOC get me to the wrong pages not showing the correct graphics. In the example clicking on TOC entry "B" does not get me to graphics "B".

Is there a way to get correct references to my images?

Comment: For the sake of the community, could you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that shows your setup? Don't use `myplot.pdf`, but rather `example-image` and such from [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set an anchor using `\phantomsection`. And I would use a `minipage` or `\parbox` to ensure that both `\phantomsection` and `\includegraphics` are on the same page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Start}
\begin{center}
  \parbox{\linewidth}{
    \centering
    \phantomsection
    \includegraphics{mwe/example-image-a.pdf}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{A}
  }
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  \parbox{\linewidth}{
    \centering
    \phantomsection
    \includegraphics{mwe/example-image-a.pdf}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{A}
  }
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  \parbox{\linewidth}{
    \centering
    \phantomsection
    \includegraphics{mwe/example-image-a.pdf}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{A}
  }
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  \parbox{\linewidth}{
    \centering\phantomsection
    \includegraphics{mwe/example-image-b.pdf}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{B}
  }
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  \parbox{\linewidth}{
    \centering
    \phantomsection
    \includegraphics{mwe/example-image-a.pdf}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{A}
  }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do I need both `\centering`? How would `\minipage` be different and is it better?

Comment: The outer `center` environment inserts additional vertical space and prevents a possible parindent. The inner `\centering` command centers your graphics horizontally. `minipage` is an Environment while `\parbox` is a command. The result would be the same.